# PHP how to array_count_values with key values array that contains alphabets integers together

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I encountered problem using array count to count string occurrences in array.

I think problem could be that array count could count occurrences of string if the string contain alphabets and digits together. Is there any possible way to count these set of datas in an array?

```
   Array ( 
          [0] => Array ( 
                          [January 2014] => 47  
                        ) 
          [1] => Array (
                          [January 2014] => 23 
                        )
          [2] => Array ( 
                          [January 2014] => 8
                        ) 
         )
```

Comment: Is that a real var_dump of your array?

Comment: Hi @MarkBaker , Nope. I just edited the array. It's my output of array using print_r() ;)

Comment: I suspect you need to simplify your array by eliminating the top-level before using a simply `array_count_values(array_keys())` on it

Comment: what are you trying to count? the number of 'January 2014' elements?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that it's a nested array

```
$myArray = array(
    array('January 2014'=>117),
    array('January 2014'=>195),
    array('February 2014'=>45),
);

$newArray = array();
$keys = array_walk(
    $myArray,
    function($value, $key) use (&$newArray) {
        $newkey = key($value);
        if (isset($newArray[$newkey]))
            $newArray[$newkey]++;
        else 
            $newArray[$newkey] = 1;
    }
);
var_dump($newArray);
```